# Relating energy density between anisotropy field and Stoner-Wohlfarth model

Tags: magnetic-fields, material-science, magnetic-moment, ferromagnetism

At this point I'm not sure if there is a jump in the text or there is a gap in my understanding.

Here goes:

Consider a uniaxial single domain crystal in which the magnetisation direction for the domain is along the easy axis. Upon being in the presence of an externally applied **transverse** magnetic field $\vec{B_{ext}}$ = $\langle 0, 0, B_{ext}\rangle$, the energy density is

$E = K Sin^{2}\theta - \mu_{0} B_{ext}M_{s}sin\theta$

where the first term is the anisotropy energy (energy required to aligned an arbitrarily pointed magnetisation direction with easy axis) and the second term being the energy required by the externally applied magnetic field to deviate the magnetisation direction away from the easy axis by an angle $\theta$.

[image]

In reading the Stoner-Wohlfarth particle describing an ellipsoid particle that is uniformly magnetised with uniaxial anisotropy, in the presence of an externally applied field that is an angle $\alpha$ to the anisotropy axis has an energy density

$E = Ksin^{2}\theta - \mu_{0} M_{s} B_{ext} cos(\alpha - \theta)$

The two energy density expression looks very familiar to each other, differing only by the $cosine$. How do I reconcile the $cosine$ term with the $sine$ term?

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: What value does $\alpha$ take in the first case?

Comment: @Anyon It is not mentioned but it should be greater than $\theta$ given the setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transverse field direction is always defined as being perpendicular to some predefined direction, commonly taken to be the easy axis or the magnetic moment direction. In the first case you describe these are the same. From your figure and description, we may say the easy axis lies in the $xy$-plane, with a fully transverse field applied along $\hat{z}$. Thus the angle $\alpha=\pi/2$, and you can use $\cos \left( \alpha-\theta\right)=\sin \theta$.

Comment: Thank you, Sir.